# Read SQL Table Manipulate The Data Output To ListView

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm using VB 2008 to access data from multiple databases, SQL Server and Access. For this query, I'm pulling data from an SQL table named "People" and displaying the results in ListView1. The "Time" column is in seconds. I have a function I use to convert seconds to minutes and seconds but I'm having a hard time merging the functions where when I pull the data from the database, populate the Name column in the listview and then run the conversion calculation on the seconds, then populate the Time column with the converted time.

```
    strsql = "SELECT Name, Time from People WHERE Boss ='" & BossSelector1.Text & "'"
    'Connection

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    While (dr.Read())
        With ListView1.Items.Add(dr("Name"))
            .subitems.add(dr("Time"))
        End With
    End While
```

Time Conversion Code

```
    Dim iSecond As Double = inputtime.Text
    Dim iSpan As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(iSecond)
    time.Text = iSpan.Minutes.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & _
                        iSpan.Seconds.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
```

I only have read only access to the SQL server so I cannot make any stored procedures to take care of my problem.

Comment: "having a hard time" does not help to understand the question. Do you get an exception, wrong result or what else? It's also not clear how the problem is related to the `ListView`.

Comment: Thank you Tim for the comment. I am unable to pass the data from the "Time" section of the strsql into anything that can process the conversion then add it back to the listview as a subitem. I'm not really sure how to manipulate the data this way.